# How would I extract only the latest week from a select over statement in Hiveql?

Tags: sql, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group, gaps-and-islands

I need some help, I've created a query which keeps a running total of whether an element returns a 1 or 0 against a specific measure with the running total returning to 0 if the measure provides a 0, Example below:

```
year_week  element  measure  running_total
2020_40    A        1        1
2020_41    A        1        2
2020_42    A        1        3
2020_43    A        0        0
2020_44    A        1        1
2020_45    A        1        2
2020_40    B        1        1
2020_41    B        1        2
2020_42    B        1        3
2020_43    B        1        4
2020_44    B        1        5
2020_45    B        1        6
```

The above is achieved using this query:

```
SELECT element,
       year_week,
       measure,
       SUM(measure) OVER (PARTITION BY element, flag_sum ORDER BY year_week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
          SUM(measure_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY element ORDER BY year_week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS flag_sum
      FROM (
        SELECT *,
            CASE WHEN  measure = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS measure_flag
        FROM database.table ) x ) y
```

This is great and works - but I'd like to provide only the latest weeks data for each element. So in the above example it would be:

```
year_week  element  measure  running_total
2020_45    A        1        2
2020_45    B        1        6
```

Essentially I need to keep the logic the same but limit the returned data set. I've attempted this however it changes the result from the correct running total to a 1 or 0.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another level of nesting, and filter the latest record per `element` with `row_number()`.

I would suggest:

```
select element, year_week, measure, running_total
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by element, grp order by year_week) - 1 as running_total
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(1 - measure) over(partition by element order by year_week) as grp,
            row_number() over(partition by element order by year_week desc) as rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

I simplified the query a little, considering the fact that `measure` has values `0` and `1` only, as showed in your sample data. If that's not the case, then:

```
select element, year_week, measure, running_total
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(measure) over(partition by element, grp order by year_week) as running_total
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(case when measure = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by element order by year_week) as grp,
            row_number() over(partition by element order by year_week desc) as rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This looks great - I'll look to implement this and let you know how it goes. Thank you for your help!